# How to work on meteor Variable & Having an issue with miniMongo

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, meteor

I'm new to meteor.js.

In the application i'm working on, users can post things on the website, and the users can comment it, like on a social network. Then i have :

```
{{#each posts}}
  {{>onePost}}
{{/each}}
```

In my onePost template, i print the onePost text and its date of publishing. But the date has been added in mongoDB thanks to `new Date();` which add the GMT data at the end.

I'd like to know can i shorten the string to x char. I know that in javascript, we have to use the `.substring(int, int) methods`, but how do i apply such a member on a meteor variable like this ?

```
<h6>date</h6>
```

as none of the following seems to work :

```
<h6>{{date}}.substring(0,3);</h6>
<h6>{{date.substring(0,3);}}</h6>
```

I do have another trouble, as i was testing, i called a method on the console in order to empty my posts collection and clear a bit my page.
But since that, i'm unable to type text again. As i validate my post, i only see [object Object]

Here is my code to insert in my collection :

```
Template.post.events({
    'keyup .comment':function(evt,tmpl){
        if(evt.which === 13 && !evt.shiftKey){
            var commenttext = tmpl.find('.comment').value;
            var options = {text:commenttext,parent:this._id};
            Meteor.call('addPost',options);
            $('.comment').val('').select().focus();
        }
    }
})
```

Here is how i handle my collection :

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Meteor.methods({
//{text:'',owner:'',date:'',parent:''}
'addPost':function(options){
    var post = {
        text:options.text,
        owner:Meteor.userId(),
        date:new Date(),
        parent:options.parent
    }
    Posts.insert(post);
},
'removePost':function(id){
    Posts.remove({_id:id});
},
'removeAllPosts':function(){
    Posts.remove({});
}
```

})

And since i callec Meteor.call('removeAllPosts'); in the Firefix js console, everything I post has the text : [object Object]

I thought that, for a reason i don't know, it now consider the return of the query to be a list of instances, but as it display correctly the author name, I rather think that it comes from the insertion in the collection. But i haven't changed anything with the nsertion function.

Comment: A meteor reset didnt changeed anything

Comment: Resolved ! But i have absolutely no idea of how i did it :/ I simply rewrote my entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do this in your helper like so:

```
{{date.toString.substring 0 3}}
```

However, I'd recommend using a helper instead:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  formattedDate: function() {
    return this.date.toString().substring(0, 3);
  }
});
```

```html
{{#each posts}}
  <h6>{{formattedDate}}</h6>
  {{>onePost}}
{{/each}}
```

Or if you want to make it more generic:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  shorten: function(data) {
    return data.toString().substring(0, 3);
  }
});
```

```html
{{#each posts}}
  <h6>{{shorten date}}</h6>
  {{>onePost}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Best explanation i could have about helpers use. Thanks you a lot !

Comment: Yes good point. I updated the answer to reflect this, however I still think a helper should be used here. It seems like a mixing of concerns to have formatting logic directly in the template.